# Chrome Extension Error MANIFEST-000001: Unable to create sequential file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-chrome-storage

Hey I currently work on a chrome-extension myself and running into following error for now reaseon.

`IO error: .../MANIFEST-000001: Unable to create sequential file (ChromeMethodBFE: 7::NewSequentialFile::4)`

> I use chrome`s local storage to save user configuration.
> I got rid of the original code who caused it, but I noticed that any kind of accessing the googles chrome local storage results in the error too.
> Like that:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(data) {
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    }else {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

> This error occured when I tried out my "delete" method which kinda works but apperently works too good.

As Google does not provide any kind of documentation regarding this error-code, I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

When you encountered this error, you likely managed to delete the entire Chrome-Extension folder.  **Congratulations.**

#### It aint that bad, you can still fix it:

1. Go to the [following site](https://chrome://extensions/) and remove your buggy extension.

   > [chrome://extensions/](https://chrome://extensions/)
2. Now go to your Chrome-Extensions Folder (the one you are working on) and rename it.
3. Then add it back to chrome.

   > [chrome://extensions/](https://chrome://extensions/)

#### What happened?

> Chrome saves your data at `C:\Users\[login_name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions` <sup>(by default)</sup>. If you managed to delete the whole folder of your extension, Chrome doesnt know where to put the files. This results in "*`MANIFEST-000001: Unable to create sequential file`*" . You cant just create a new folder with the same ID and a version_folder inside of it, as the essential data is still missing. Since you also cannot change the ID of your Chrome extension, you are left with no choice but to create a new extension.